# Powershell silent / unattended install of Delphi Tokyo 10.2 - for CI use in win docker container

Tags: powershell, delphi, continuous-integration, silent, silent-installer

I'm attempting to create a powershell command that silently installs Delphi Tokyo 10.2 - to be used as an automated compiler in a Windows Docker container. I've not been able to find any recent documentation on how to implement an unattended/silent installation using the proper installer commands / switches.

I was able to determine that the Tokyo and Rio installers use Inno Setup  - and should be given Inno Setup installer [commands/switches](https://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

From the Tokyo installer about page:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/88jY7PF2mPAipwEA9

This is the command I've messed with thus far:

```
.\radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.exe /sp- /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /norestart/ /log="c:\somelocation\install.log"
```

However I am not able to get the install process to go past the first page or EULA checkbox. The failed silent install log shows:

```
Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-05:00)
Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (u)
Original Setup EXE: C:\somelocation\radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.exe
Setup command line: /SL5="$18051C,138809719,642048,C:\somelocation\radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.exe" /sp- /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /norestart/ /log=c:\somelocation\install.log
Windows version: 10.0.18363  (NT platform: Yes)
64-bit Windows: Yes
Processor architecture: x64
User privileges: Administrative
64-bit install mode: No
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1QQ8P.tmp
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1QQ8P.tmp\innocallback.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1QQ8P.tmp\UnlockFirewall.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1QQ8P.tmp\mOasisRuntime.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1QQ8P.tmp\topbanner96.bmp
Failed to proceed to next wizard page; aborting.
Got EAbort exception.
Deinitializing Setup.
Log closed.
```

Here's a portion of the logs from a non-silent install of the same installer package:

```
Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-05:00)
Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (u)
Original Setup EXE: C:\somelocation\radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.exe
Setup command line: /SL5="$405F0,138809719,642048,C:\somelocation\radstudio10_2_3_esd__93231.exe" /log=c:\somelocation\install.log /saveinf=c:\somelocation\install.inf
Windows version: 10.0.18363  (NT platform: Yes)
64-bit Windows: Yes
Processor architecture: x64
User privileges: Administrative
264-bit install mode: No
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\innocallback.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\UnlockFirewall.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\mOasisRuntime.dll
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\topbanner96.bmp
Message box (OK):
Inno Setup version 5.5.6 (u)
Copyright © 1997-2015 Jordan Russell
Portions Copyright © 2000-2015 Martijn Laan
All rights reserved.

Inno Setup home page:
http://www.innosetup.com/

RemObjects Pascal Script home page:
http://www.remobjects.com/ps
User chose OK.
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\ProductCodes.ini
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\ProductCodes.ini
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\ProductCodes.ini
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\ProductCodes.ini
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-K4M7F.tmp\ProductCodes.ini
Starting the installation process.
Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero
Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio
Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0
Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\
...
...
...
```

So in the above successful non-silent install - notice the line in the logs that says `Message box (OK)` this occurs after I accept the EULA. So at present i'm not sure how to pass an installer switch to suffice the EULA page silently.

Has anyone had success with creating a silent / unattended install of Delphi Tokyo or Rio? Or has found documentation that helped them achieve something similar?

Any help is much appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Comment: Have you tried .\radstudio10_2_3.exe /?
Often the installer itself will provide the switches it can accept.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. No I hadn't tried that. However, it appears to match the documentation I linked on the Inno Setup installer switches.

Comment: I have been looking at trying to do this as well. I have had no luck either and am stuck in the same spot

Comment: What's the full log?

Comment: Where/how did you determine that the RAD Studio installer is based on Inno Setup? AFAIK, they're still using InstallShield, since the time they were partnered with them and bundled IS as an installation tool in the RAD Studio product itself. (They stopped doing so due to a feud that IIRC had to do with licensing and the two companies parted ways.)

Comment: Should have mentioned that InstallShield's introduction was back in the Inprise Corporation timeframe. I also seem to recall that it was in the days when you were supposed to (required, maybe?) to use an Inprise-certified installer, but I could be remembering that wrong. Maybe Remy Lebeau will remember this and can provide the details - he was on Team B back then.

Comment: Hey Ken, that was what I had thought initially too but when I tried using InstallShield installer switches nothing worked - which prompted me to check the about page on the installer: https://photos.app.goo.gl/88jY7PF2mPAipwEA9

Comment: @mirtheil I've added more logging. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Delphi 2007` and `Delphi XE2` we were able to do a silent installation with `setup.exe /s`, see https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/07/unattended-delphi-installation-how.html for reference.

But this did not work for `Delphi 10.2 Tokyo` anymore. So our IT department **called Embarcadero directly** for more information on how to do a silent installation. But unfortunately they told us, the **installation process can not be done silently**!

Comment: Noooo! Well, that stinks. Thanks for sharing - I think I'll give Embarcadero support a call anyway and let them know that this would be a valuable feature.
Thanks again.