How to run Delphi silent installer on a machine that has no valid license?
I want to install Delphi 11 automatically. I use a .cmd script to start the installer in silent mode, and perform some additional tasks. It works if Delphi was already installed because it finds the .slip file. The installation is almost unattended. It requires only two keystrokes at the beginning.
But when I want to install Delphi in a brand-new computer I don't have a .slip file, so the installer will simply stop. This makes the silent installer pretty much useless.
The documentation says that I can provide a .slip file via command line. But obviously I don't have a .slip file yet.
The documentation end here.
Dirty workarounds:

I was thinking maybe I can obtain a slip file for the Community edition, start the silent installer using that file, then once Delphi is installed delete the slip file in order to start the real activation process...
The classic (non-silent) installer has an option called something like "I have signed up for a free License". But I don't see a command line for this, in the silent installer.

Any better ideas?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216302/powershell-silent-unattended-install-of-delphi-tokyo-10-2-for-ci-use-in-win

This won't help you here, but if you were hosting the licenses yourself on an Emparcadero license server, you could simply export such a slip file and use it for the silent installation. (If yo need more info on that, google for "Delphi network named user".)
